# Compare column value at one time to another pandas datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime index and some column, 'value'. I would like to compare the 'value' value at a given time of day to the value at a different time of the same day. E.g. compare the 10am value to the 10pm value.

Right now I can get the value at either side using:

```
mask = df[(df.index.hour == hour)]
```

the problem is that this returns a dataframe indexed at hour. So doing mask1.value - mask2.value returns Nan's since the indexes are different.

I can get around this in a convoluted way:

`out = mask.value.loc["2020-07-15"].reset_index() - mask2.value.loc["2020-07-15"].reset_index() #assuming mask2 is the same as the mask call but at a different hour`

but this is tiresome to loop over for a dataset that spans years. (Obviously I could timedelta +=1 in the loop to avoid the hard calls).

I don't actually care if some nan's get into the end result if some, e.g. 10am, values are missing.

Edit:

Initial dataframe:

```
index                  values
2020-05-10T10:00:00     23
2020-05-10T11:00:00     20
2020-05-10T12:00:00     5
.....
2020-05-30T22:00:00     8
2020-05-30T23:00:00     8
2020-05-30T24:00:00     9
```

Expected dataframe:

```
index        date         newval
  0         2020-05-10     18
.....
  x         2020-05-30     1
```

where newval is some subtraction of the two different times I described above (eg. the 10am measurement - the 12pm measurement so 23-5 = 18), second entry is made up

it doesn't matter to me if date is a separate column or the index.

Comment: Welcome! could you please provide initial dataframe and expected dataframe?

Comment: Added initial and expected dataframe to original post

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

```
mask1 = df[(df.index.hour == hour1)]
mask2 = df[(df.index.hour == hour2)]
out = mask1.values - mask2.values # df.values returns an np array without indices
result_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.daterange(start,end), data=out)
```

It should save you the effort of looping over the dates